# dirac delta definition equivalent

Tags: dirac-delta

in below link, (formula (34)-(40)) there are some definition of Dirac delta function in terms of other functions such as Airy function, Bessel function of the first kind, Laguerre polynomial,....

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Is there any definition of the Dirac delta function in terms of the sech (secant hyperbolic) or cosh (cosine hyperbolic) functions?

Please say your references. Thanks

Comment: I imagine it is possible to construct some. A question is why?

Comment: thank you simonS.yes,why and what is that function?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever $f$ is a nonnegative function with integral 1, one has approximation by convolution. Specifically, define $f_c(x) = f(x/c)/c$. Then $\lim_{c \to 0^+} g * f_c = g$ for mildly restricted $g$. (For example, $L^p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$ is enough.) In particular you can take $f(x)=\text{sech}(x)/\pi$.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The delta "function" $\delta(x)$ is supposed to be zero as $x$ gets large in either direction, so basing one on $\cosh(x)$ is hard because  $\cosh(x) \to +\infty$ as $x$ gets large in either direction.  That makes $\operatorname{sech} (x)$ a good candidate.  Since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \operatorname{sech} x dx=\pi$, you can use $\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac k \pi \operatorname{sech} (kx)$ as a delta "function".

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. is "(Sqrt[k]/Pi).Sech[kx] " is a delta function?(for k>infinity ,it's integral becomes zero).thank you a lot.

Comment: You need the integral to stay $1$, as that is part of the delta function definition.  That is why I made it proportional to $k$.  The $k$ in the integral narrows it up, and the $k$ outside makes the peak tall.